# control panel to see running applications

Tags: 12.04

I would like to see what are all the applications/process being run at present in my Ubuntu system. is it possible to get the list of running applications, and how to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/182137/how-do-i-know-which-processes-are-running-and-who-own-the-process

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open `System Monitor` using the Dash to view your running applications/processes. This essentially does the same thing as Windows Task Manager.  It is a graphical GNOME program, its name if you want to invoke it from a terminal is `gnome-system-monitor`.

[image]

[image]

For the command line, you have several options from a simple `ps -aef` (just prints a list) to `top` (a scrollable list) or even `htop` (fancier than `top`, not installed by default):

[image]

Comment: These are all processes. How do you list only the "applications"? The ones you can traverse in the UI with Alt+Tab?

Answer (score 3):

Command line way of getting information about running processes,

```
ps aux
```

Comment: downvote reason please.

Answer (score 2):

You can install BUM package to see all daemons and services that run at startup or are just some kind of zombies on your Ubuntu system. It looks like you are looking for the MSCONFIG app from windows so you can stop services and daemons that you never use like scanning, printing and many many others. You can install BUM with this code:

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

You can use bum right away after install but please be careful and do not stop a whole bunch of services at once. Stop what you think you don't need step by step, and check after each reboot if all seems to be ok with your system. Bum can harm your system if you don't use it with extreme care. After BUM loads, you can see an ADVANCED button at the bottom of the window. Press it so you be able to get more info about your running services and so on.

You can also use [GNOME Session Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-session-common/) to be able to stop, start or restart your  startup applications. It is not as reliable as bum but it has a friendly interface and it can be of some use to you too. Use Software Center or Synaptic to install this last one.

Answer (score 1):

There are some possibilities:
This command will output on terminal:

```
top
ps aux
```

This command will open window System Monitor:

```
gnome-system-monitor
```