# which process is slowing the system?

Tags: 14.04

In windows we can find the max memory process from task manager process tab(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>sht</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>) and can kill it.

Is there a similar way to find out the process running ordered by the memory usage and kill the max memory process ?

Is there any GUI tool like the task manager in windows for Ubuntu ?

Comment: yes i got solution over there, thanks. and do you know how to clean up the buffered memory, which system had used earlier and if freed same memory can be used again by different processese

Comment: Please create a new question to cover this topic. That's an interesting one btw

Comment: There is absolutely no need or benefit from "clean[ing] the [main] memory" on both Linux or Windows (and OS X for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never clean the memory of any machine, modern systems manage RAM very well and killing applications can be harmful.

Use `top` (or `htop` for a more fancy interface) to discover what is clogging your system and close those applications through their interfaces.

Comment: htop is good looking and easy to interpret user interface, and why is cleaning memory harmful can you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `top` command.
It should do what you're looking for.

You can also consider the installation of `htop` which is a bit more user friendly than `top`.

As for the GUI in gnome or unity there is a task manager you should look for it in the main unity/gnome menu.

Comment: thanks for the answer but http://askubuntu.com/questions/446372/control-pannel-to-see-running-applications is easy way to do it. do you have any answer for the last question ?

Comment: @mateen please ask one question at a time next time.

Comment: @Kiwy sorry for multiple question i ll post it as a new question